# Reverse direction on collision

Tags: ios, objective-c

Been going through an xCode book trying to learn how to program for iOS. Ran into a problem.. I got mostly everything working besides the paddle collision in my app. I made a simple pin ball game and when the ball hits the blocks the blocks break and the ball will come back down, the problem that I have is when the ball comes down it doesn't recognize the collision and goes right through the paddle.

the problem is is checkCollisionWithBlocks

Not sure exactly how I would change the direction of the ball when it hits so it does not go through the paddle:

```
-(void)checkCollisionWithScreenEdges{
    if(ballRect.origin.x <= 0){
        ballVelocity.x = abs(ballVelocity.x);
    }
    if(ballRect.origin.x >= VIEW_WIDTH - BALL_SIZE){
        ballVelocity.x = -1 * abs(ballVelocity.x);
    }
    if(ballRect.origin.y <= 0){
        ballVelocity.y = abs(ballVelocity.y);
    }
    if(ballRect.origin.y >= VIEW_HEIGHT - BALL_SIZE){
        ballRect.origin.x = 180.0;
        ballRect.origin.y = 220.0;
        ballVelocity.y = -1*abs(ballVelocity.y);
    }
}

-(void)checkCollisionWithBlocks{
    for(mmBlockView* blockView in blocks){
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(blockView.frame,ballRect)){
            ballVelocity.y = -ballVelocity.y;
            [blocks removeObject:blockView];
            [blockView removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)checkCollisionWithPaddle{
    if(ballRect.origin.x <= 0){
        ballVelocity.x = abs(ballVelocity.x);
    }
    if(ballRect.origin.x >= VIEW_WIDTH - BALL_SIZE){
        ballVelocity.x = -1 * abs(ballVelocity.x);
    }
    if(ballRect.origin.y <= 0){
        ballVelocity.y = abs(ballVelocity.y);
    }
    if(ballRect.origin.y >= VIEW_HEIGHT - BALL_SIZE){
        ballRect.origin.x = 180.0;
        ballRect.origin.y = 220.0;
        ballVelocity.y = -1*abs(ballVelocity.y);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`checkCollisionWithPaddle` is not, despite the name, checking for a collision with the paddle, it's checking to see if the ball is going off the screen.

To check if it's colliding with the paddle, you might do something like:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(paddleView.frame, ballRect))
```

If it helps, you might think of the paddle as being like a block, except that it can move (and doesn't go away when you hit it :-)